# Base64 decoding a normal unencoded string in android not give any exception

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Decoding with base64 an unencoded string on Android does not gives any error but returns a string with some special characters e.g encoded like. 
It should throw some IllegalArgumentException. Is there some native way in android to check that other than regex ?

`private String decodeThisString = "I am a java String";
 bytes[] deocdedBytes = Base64.decode(decodeThisString.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);`

Comment: Where are you obtaining your string from? Can you use Java 8's `java.util.Base64.Decoder`?

Comment: Thanks but No, we need to use below Java 8 because Java 8 above methods required minimum API level 26.

Comment: Try to change flags of encoding and explicitly set utf-8 encoding

Answer (score 1):

I think you do not need to remove the character when you will decode it, automatically they will be discarded at the time of decode. I have tested with encoding and decoding with the provided code and get the exact string after decode.

```
String decodeThisString = "I am a java String";
//encode
byte[] data = Base64.encode(decodeThisString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), Base64.DEFAULT);
String text = new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

//decode
byte[] datas = Base64.decode(text, Base64.DEFAULT);
String texts = new String(datas, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```